# How can I run Cygwin Terminal under a current Cygwin installation under Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, terminal, cygwin

In the past I have used Cygwin Terminal, i.e. a window similar in external appearance and external behavior to the DOS/Windows command line window that runs natively under Windows.

Right now, in my start menu, I see what appear to be GUI options (namely, Fluxbox, FVWM, GNOME Flashback (Metacity), GNOME-Openbox, KDE-Openbox, LXDE, LXQt Desktop, Openbox, Plasma, UserScript, WindowMaker, XLaunch, XWin Server).

Does Cygwin still offer the facility of an old-style Cygwin Terminal without invoking an open-source GUI? If so, how? If not, what is the easiest way to do the job of the oldschool Cygwin Terminal shell window?

Comment: It seems that you have switched to Cygwin/X. While you still can use mintty (a very good terminal IMO), you can also use one of the X terminals which you have available now (rxvt, xterm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Does Cygwin still offer the facility of an old-style Cygwin Terminal?

The "old style" terminal is `mintty`. To run it:

```
G:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe
```

I have `cygwin` installed on drive G:

You can add a link to it in your start menu or your taskbar.